# strip.text does not work with labeller - facet_wrap ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am using facet_wrap and need expression in header so I am using labeller. But then strip.text does not work (I want the header to be in bold). see code:

```
sc <- c("Ref","DJ","DT","DTHW")
vars <- c("O2","PO4","NH4","NO3")
df1 <- data.frame(scenario=rep(sc,4),variable=rep(vars,each=4),pct=runif(16,-10,10))

ggplot(df1, aes(y= scenario, x=pct)) +
  geom_col(aes( fill = scenario), position = position_dodge()) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(variable)) +
  theme (strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

This gives bold header as expected:

[image]

But if I add the expression with labeller:

```
vars2plot <- c(expression(paste("Hypol. ",O[2])),expression(paste("Epil. ",PO[4]^"3-")),
               expression(paste("Epil. ",NH[4]^"+")), expression(paste("Hypol. ",NO[3]^"-")))
names(vars2plot) <- vars
df1$variable <- factor(df1$variable, levels = vars, labels = vars2plot)

ggplot(df1, aes(y= scenario, x=pct)) +
  geom_col(aes( fill = scenario), position = position_dodge()) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(variable), labeller = labeller(variable=label_parsed)) +
  theme (strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

The bold does not appear:

[image]

Any ideas how to make the header bold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use expressions, then you need to use the `plotmath` syntax to make things bold. You cannot use font properties to alter the appearance. You can wrap your expressions in `bold()` with

```
vars2plot <- c(expression(paste("Hypol. ",O[2])),expression(paste("Epil. ",PO[4]^"3-")),
               expression(paste("Epil. ",NH[4]^"+")), expression(paste("Hypol. ",NO[3]^"-")))

# or simplified ...
# vars2plot <- expression(
#   "Hypol. " ~ O[2],
#   "Epil. " ~ PO[4]^"3-",
#   "Epil. " ~ NH[4]^"+",
#   "Hypol. " ~ NO[3]^"-")

# now make them all bold
vars2plot <- as.expression(lapply(vars2plot, function(x) bquote(bold(.(x)))))
```

which will output
[image: bold expressions in facet strips]